# Как подключить json яндекс карты в WP?

Tags: php, wordpress, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Как подключить json файл с массовом меток в яндекс карте?

```js
  ymaps.ready(function () {
  
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.73973206899513,37.60550799999995],
            zoom: 13,
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
          // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
          clusterize: true,
          // ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
          gridSize: 32,
          clusterDisableClickZoom: true
      });
  objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenDotIcon');
  objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenClusterIcons');
  myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
  $.ajax({
      url:  "js/assets/js/data.json"
  }).done(function(data) {
      objectManager.add(data);
  });
  myMap.controls.remove('geolocationControl');
  myMap.controls.remove('searchControl');
  myMap.controls.remove('trafficControl');
  myMap.controls.remove('typeSelector');
  myMap.controls.remove('fullscreenControl');
  myMap.controls.remove('rulerControl');
  myMap.behaviors.disable(['scrollZoom']);
        $('#Moscow').click(function(){
          myMap.setCenter([ 55.73973206899513,37.60550799999995], 13, {
            checkZoomRange: true
        });
        });
        $('#Buzuluk').click(function(){
          myMap.setCenter([ 53.75672207079035,41.02551099999998], 14, {
            checkZoomRange: true
        });
        });
        $('#Tyumen').click(function(){
          myMap.setCenter([ 52.93639757143206,102.79593349999993], 14, {
            checkZoomRange: true
        });
        });

//отключаем зум колёсиком мышки
myMap.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');
 
//на мобильных устройствах... (проверяем по userAgent браузера)
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    //... отключаем перетаскивание карты
    myMap.behaviors.disable('drag');
}
  });
```

Увы  get_template_directory_uri() не помогает, выдает ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас файл меток находится в папке темы, то строка с URL должна выглядеть так

```
url: "/wp-content/themes/моя-тема/js/assets/js/data.json"
```

Comment: Я то это понимаю, но как правильно указать путь если путь get_template_directory_uri() я не могу прописать?

Comment: зачем вам тут `get_template_directory_uri`? Я вам написал готовое решение. Вы просто в скрипт, который запускается через wp_enqueue_script, добавить php-код не можете. Вам надо или inline скрипт делать, встроенный в php-файл, и тогда можно. Но это плохо. Используйте wp_enqueue_script и wp_localize_script - так правильно.